# In Swig, how do I handle a function that is supposed to update the contents of a string?

Tags: c, ruby, swig

I am using swig to generate some wrappers from c to ruby.

A few of the functions are expecting me to pass in a char * which will be updated.

for example:

```
void setvarc(int arg1, char * arg2);
```

I think in the ruby class that will interface with the function I can use String.new to create a string large enough to hold the data and then just pass that to the function.

so something like this:

```
return_string = " " * 10
setvarc(arg1, return_string)
```

but this is not a very nice solution, and is very non-ruby like.

I see in chapter 9 of the swig manual how to use typemaps to handle arguments but that does not allocate space.
I think I need to create a small c wrapper around this function and allocate the space, but then I have to clean it up after the return.  Swig seems to have some typemaps that might handle that as well, but this not really a good example on how to do this.

This seems like something that would come up fairly often.

I am thinking it should be something like this.
(my c is rusty so this could be wrong, but you get the idea)

```
char * get_value(int arg1) {
   char * buffer = malloc(some_number);
   setvarc(arg1,buffer);
   return buffer
}
```

and then some swig typemaps that hopefully would make ruby take a copy of the new string and free up the space.

Does anyone have an example of how to tie this all together?

Comment: If you export the get_value that returns a char*, does SWIG not generate a ruby function that returns a ruby string? you'd have to inline the get_value in the %{]% section of .i and declare it in the .i body.

Comment: I think this pretty much what I did (see my own answer below).  The only other thing I did was to add the malloc and freearg.  I don't think was totally required but the swig manual cautions against passing in non-read only strings, so I felt this was the safest way to handle this.

Comment: Where are you passing in a non read only string if you export getvalue and not setvarc? With a char* as a return value and an Int as an arg I don't see why you need any typemap stuff.

Comment: I would have to go back and rerun it, but I think you are totally correct the way you are describing this.  The only reason for the type map is to free the space allocated in side the get_value function by the malloc. setvarc, expects to be passed a string long enough to hold the result it will copy into it.  Since the swig manual cautions against passing in a char * from the scripting language and allowing the c function from modifying it, I created a new char * pointing to newly allocated memory.  I _think_ with out the freearg type map, this would be a memory leak.

Comment: I think I'm not being clear in this small space what I mean. I will put an answer later and you will see how SWIG can do everything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get away with just the following:

```
%ignore setvarc;

%newobject get_value;  

%inline %{
    char* get_value(int argc)
    {
       char * buffer = malloc(some_number);
       setvarc(arg1,buffer);
       return buffer;
    }
%}
```

SWIG should wrap get_value as a Ruby string and take ownership of the memory allocated by the function (because of %newobject).

Comment: This works almost exactly like the technique I used above but seems cleaner.  Both generated a free() before returning.  The only difference I saw was that the freearg typemap generated a free for the fail case as well as the success case.  Thanks for the help Scholli!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: While this works fine the accepted answer is a little bit cleaner**

I figured it out, here is an example if anyone needs it:

```
/* set a type map for the next set of functions */
/* it just needs to match any arg so it will get triggered */

%typemap(freearg) char {
  free(result);
}

/* create a simple interface that will allocate the required space */
char *get_value(FACREF *facref, char mode);
%inline %{
char *get_value(FACREF *facref, char mode) {
   int fac_size = facref->length + 1;
   char *result = (char *) malloc((sizeof(char) * fac_size) + 1);
   setvarc(facref, result, mode);
   return result;
}
%}

/* clear the typemap when done */
%typemap(in) char;
```

which swig then wraps with this code.

```
SWIGINTERN VALUE
_wrap_get_value(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self) {
  FACREF *arg1 = (FACREF *) 0 ;
  char arg2 ;
  void *argp1 = 0 ;
  int res1 = 0 ;
  char val2 ;
  int ecode2 = 0 ;
  char *result = 0 ;
  VALUE vresult = Qnil;

  if ((argc < 2) || (argc > 2)) {
    rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "wrong # of arguments(%d for 2)",argc); SWIG_fail;
  }
  res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(argv[0], &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_facref, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), Ruby_Format_TypeError( "", "FACREF *","get_value", 1, argv[0] )); 
  }
  arg1 = (FACREF *)(argp1);
  ecode2 = SWIG_AsVal_char(argv[1], &val2);
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(ecode2)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(ecode2), Ruby_Format_TypeError( "", "char","get_value", 2, argv[1] ));
  } 
  arg2 = (char)(val2);
  result = (char *)get_value(arg1,arg2);
  vresult = SWIG_FromCharPtr((const char *)result);
  {
    free(result);
  }
  return vresult;
fail:
  {
    free(result);
  }
  return Qnil;
}
```